# Floating action button is possible to hide and show but how to animate a custom view when listview or recycler view is scrolled down?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I can create a bottom floating custom view . But need to animate the view based on recycler view scrolling. When recycler view is scrolled down then view will animate like image 1 and when recycler view is scrolled up the view will be animate and set at bottom like image 2 ?

Image 1

[image]
Image 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This approach of using floating button is not standard . Refer [this](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#)